# How to transform an ast.Document to a graphql.Schema

Tags: go, graphql

I want to use the graphql type system language to create a schema that I can use for my application. In the application itself I want to hook into the resolver. The parsing of the type system files to a valid ast.Document is no problem

```
func parseSchemaToAST(t *testing.T, globalSchemaFile string) *ast.Document {
    buffer, err := ioutil.ReadFile(globalSchemaFile)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error loading global schema file %v", err)
    }

    astDoc, err := parser.Parse(parser.ParseParams{
        Source: string(buffer),
        Options: parser.ParseOptions{
            NoLocation: true,
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Parse failed: %v", err)
    }

    return astDoc
}
```

I also can transform this ast.Document back to the type system language. (via graphql/language/printer) But how should I do the transformation from ast.Document to graphql.Schema? In the graphql-js implementation I found a freaking useful function with the signature

```
function buildASTSchema(ast: Document): GraphQLSchema
```

What would be the graphql-go counterpart for that. I want to avoid a custom implementation